# Which consensus algorithm PoW or POS is used for mining a block in latest ganache ethereum client?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, ganache, ganache-cli

Which consensus algorithm have been used in the latest version of ganache for ethereum blockchain simulation.